# Remote debugging iOS webapp - stop OSX Safari web inspector panel closing

Tags: ios, safari-web-inspector

I am debugging an iOS webapp (saved to desktop) with Safari 7.0.3 and an iOS 7.1.1 iPad attached via USB.

This is working ok, but to see changes after editing the code I need to close the app and re-open, which causes the Safari web inspector to disappear - every time I need to go to the menu and click `Develop > iPad > myApp`, which gets exhausting after the 100th time.

Is there a way to test a webapp without the web inspector panel closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you just send it Javascript in the debugger console to make it reload:

```
window.location.reload()
```

?

Comment: Cool... is this possible for TVML/TVJS debugging?  (I have the same problem with needing to re-open the debugger repeatedly.)  Doesn't work in my quick test.